# Return content of txt file in self-hosted Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

I have an ASP.NET web API which was hosted using IIS, with IIS I was able to get the content of a *.txt file just by making a get request to the root of the API (http://localhost/myfile.txt) and it would return me the content of that file. After moving to use self-hosted in a windows service it is no longer able to return any content of the file and I am getting 404. Any idea on how to make this work as it used to work with IIS, I don't want to go the route of creating a controller with get request just to read the file, I want to modify it to work as IIS.

Comment: It worked because iis is a web server. You don't have a web server. You have webapi. Setup a controller method and code it to read and return the file.

Comment: That's right! would make this as an answer... thanks